# Row Count from all SQL Server Databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm planning a migration and trying to get a row count of how many rows I'll be migrating from one server to another. I've written a dynamic query that keeps timing out and I'm not sure the best way to get a row count from all the databases on the server as we have over 500 databases. I'm attaching the code below that I've written so far.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ix INT = 1;

DECLARE @temptbl TABLE (
dbname VARCHAR(500),
cnt INT
 )

 DECLARE @dbs TABLE (
dbname NVARCHAR(500)
 )
 SET @sql = CAST(N'' AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
 INSERT INTO @dbs
    SELECT
        Org_dbname
    FROM [ourdatabases].dbo.tbl_datbases om
    INNER JOIN sys.databases S
        ON om.Org_dbname = S.name
    WHERE Org_dbname IS NOT NULL

 ;


 DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(255)

 WHILE EXISTS (SELECT
    *
FROM @dbs)
 BEGIN
 SELECT TOP 1
@dbname = dbname
 FROM @dbs

 PRINT @dbname
 SELECT
@sql = @sql + N' 

use ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + ';

      SELECT

SUM(q1.[RowCount]) cnt
 FROM (SELECT
        QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id)) + ''.'' +               QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) AS [TableName]
    ,SUM(sdmvPTNS.row_count) AS [RowCount]
FROM sys.objects AS sOBJ
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS sdmvPTNS
    ON sOBJ.object_id = sdmvPTNS.object_id
WHERE sOBJ.type = ''U''
AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
AND sdmvPTNS.index_id < 2
GROUP BY    sOBJ.schema_id
        ,sOBJ.name) q1

      '

 DELETE FROM @dbs
 WHERE dbname = @dbname

 END

 SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, '');
 PRINT @sql

 INSERT INTO @temptbl

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql

 SELECT
     SUM(cnt)
 FROM @temptbl
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to see the DBName AND the row count in your output? You only have the rowcount which is count of useless by itself.

Comment: @SeanLange Currently an overall count is fine but obviously you're right I wouldn't mind grouping the counts by database name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need a cursor, a table variable or any looping here. We can leverage dynamic sql to generate a comprehensive query across all the databases. Here is how you could execute this query across every database (with a few exceptions) on your instance.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'';

select @SQL = @SQL + 
    N'SELECT DatabaseName = ''' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'''      
        ,SUM(sdmvPTNS.row_count) AS [RowCount]
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.sys.objects AS sOBJ
    INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS sdmvPTNS
        ON sOBJ.object_id = sdmvPTNS.object_id
    WHERE sOBJ.type = ''U''
    AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
    AND sdmvPTNS.index_id < 2 UNION ALL '
from sys.databases d
where name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')

set @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10) --Need to remove the last UNION ALL

--select @SQL
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: That looks so much cleaner and neater! Works a charm too. Thanks